# How do I chain angular filters that use checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, filter

I have a list of items and I need 3 filters for it. 
1 of the filters is a simple name search.
2 of these filters are checkboxes that a user can toggle to adjust their data.

Previously, when I wasn't using checkboxes (and only allowing a single value for each filter), the below line allowed all filters to be used:

```
'<tr ng-repeat="item in data.itemList | orderBy: orderField | filter: {attr1 : a1Value} | filter: {attr2: a2Value} | filter: {attr3 : a3Value}">'
```

But now that I'm using checkboxes, this no longer works.
Here is what I am trying so far.
HTML:

```
'<!--list of checkboxes-->
<dl>
    <dt ng-repeat="type in data.att1List">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="a1Obj[type]">{{att1}}
    </dt>
</dl>
<!--...-->
<!-- list of data items -->
<tr ng-repeat="item in data.itemList | orderBy: orderField | filter: {attr1 : a1Filter} | filter: {attr2: a2Obj} | filter: {name : nameValue}">
<!--...-->'
```

in the controller i have:

```
'$scope.data.att1List = ['Group','Corp','HR'];

$scope.data.itemList = [
   {name:'Zeus', attr1:'Corp', attr2:'green' },
   {name:'Athena', attr1:'HR', attr2:'blue' },
   {name:'Apollo', attr1:'Corp', attr2:'red' },
   {name:'Thor', attr1:'Group', attr2:'green' }
];

$scope.a1Obj= {
    'Group' : false,
    'HR' : false,
    'Corp' : false 
};`

$scope.a1Filter = function (itm) {
  return $scope.a1Obj[itm.attr1];
};'
```

What am I missing? Does anyone have any insight on chaining multiple filters where 1 or more are checkboxes?

Comment: can you share some data so that it can be identified what are you actually filtering

Comment: sure, i added some extra data